# Fragment Change when change permission from settings

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

Suppose i have One Activity and three Fragments which are Fragment A,B and C.When i go to the Fragment B then i go to settings and change the permission and back to my Fragment B.But unfortunately it takes me to Fragment C instead of Fragment B.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried ?

Comment: "It takes me to Fragment C" . I don't thing its happen automatically . Check your code in onresume() of Activity. Lifecycle methods calling is reason behind it.

Comment: i have not write any code in onResume().Should i write something to my onResume () of my acivity..Thanks